# 404 FIle not found

Tags: php, .htaccess, amazon-ec2, http-status-code-404, bitnami

I'm using amazon EC2, bitnami LAMP AMI. 
I recently added a folder so i can test another website out eg www.website.com/foldername/
I did chmod 777 to that folder so i can access it but the problem is i can only access the main page which is located at www.website.com/foldername/ when i click any other page it returns me

```
Not Found

The requested URL /foldername/landing was not found on this server.
```

From what i know the template worked for other people who didnt use amazon, the following is my htaccess

```
 SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV development

Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)\?*$ index.php [L,QSA]

#remove www.
#RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

#RewriteRule ^(.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|gif))$ index.php?controller=minify&action=index&file_path=$1&ext=$2 [L,NC]
#RewriteRule ^(.*\.(css|js))$ index.php?controller=minify&action=jscss&file_path=$1&ext=$2 [L,NC]

</IfModule>

ErrorDocument 404 index.php

<ifModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 216000 seconds"
</ifModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|log|sh|inc|bak|cache)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```

Hope someone could help me out here. :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually a apache issue. Sorry! :) 
I was advised not to use bitnami for production, for some reason its apache disabled some stuff, its good for development.